# TextView does not wrap contents tightly enough to center it properly in a layout

Tags: android

I am trying to center the text in a `TextView`, which itself is contained in a constraint layout. The problem is, `wrap_content` does not wrap the text tightly enough, which causes it to be off-center. I tried all gravities, making it fill the parent and then use gravities, etc. and can't think of a solution and did not find anything useful when googling.

Problem can be seen well in the layout preview:

[image: Image fails to center]

`badge.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    tools:layout_height="32dp"
    tools:layout_width="32dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/badge_background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/circle_accent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:visibility="visible"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/badge_counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:foregroundGravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/badge_background"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/badge_background"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/badge_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/badge_background"
        tools:text="21"
        tools:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/badge_watched_tick"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_watch"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/badge_background"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/badge_background"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/badge_background"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/badge_background"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try `android:includeFontPadding="false"` and see if there's any difference

Comment: Thanks, this makes it tighter, but still not tight enough, screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/powMW8s.png

Comment: Your image is centered. The 1 occupies exactly the same space as 2, but because it doesn't have a base, it looks as if there's padding on its right. Type 11 instead or 22 to see the difference

Comment: Thanks @NikosHidalgo, how can I give it a base?

Comment: find a font where 1 has a base e.g. Ubuntu Mono https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Ubuntu+Mono

Comment: Ah, I get now what you mean, but that doesn't really solve my problem. Switching to a monospaced font with number bases looks weird because those are used nowhere else in the application.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use round drawable as TextView background

Comment: Sadly doesn't help. Thanks for the attempt though :)